Internal direct sum of quotient space and subspace
I'm trying to (thoroughly) understand quotient spaces in linear algebra as I'm looking into geometric control. I, however, seem to keep running into discrepancies in papers, which makes me question my understanding. For example, in the paper "Repeated eigenstructure assignment for controlled invariant subspaces" (Ntogramatzidis et al., 2015), there is this statement involving a direct sum:

Here, $\mathcal{X}$ is a vector space and $\mathcal{R}_{0}, \mathcal{V} \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ are subspace. But to me the internal direct sum $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{V} + \mathcal{R}_{0}$ does not make any sense, as $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{R}_{0}$ both contain different elements (here, $\mathcal{R}_{0}$ contains vectors $\boldsymbol{x}$, whilst $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{V}$ contains affine subsets parallel to $\mathcal{V}$)? How can one sum these vector spaces?
I noticed a similar discrepancy in "Revealing stealthy attacks in control systems" (Teixeira et al., 2012), where they state:


Again, to me, this statement seems incorrect as $\boldsymbol{z}_{0} \in \mathcal{V}^{\star}$, but $\boldsymbol{z}_{0}$ can't be an element of $\mathcal{V} / \mathcal{T}_{\mathrm{u}}$, as the quotient space contains entire sets (which themselves contain "vectors"), not "vectors" like $\boldsymbol{z}_{0}$.
I'm aware that what makes something a vector is that it belongs to a vector space, which the quotient space is, but to me, these vectors can still be very different and, therefore, 'incompatible'.

To make a long story short, are these indeed mistakes in these papers, or is there something fundamental I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated!

I don't understand what issue you have with the second example. It clearly says $z_0 \in \mathcal{V}^{\star} / \mathcal{T}_u$. Where you get $z_0 \in \mathcal{V}^{\star}$ from I have no idea.

To give context: we have a vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with a vector (i.e., an ordered $n$-tuple of real numbers) $\boldsymbol{z}{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $\mathcal{V}^{\star}, \mathcal{T}{\mathrm{u}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are subspace of that vector spaces, meaning their elements are ordered $n$-tuples as well. Specifically, in the paper, $\boldsymbol{z}{0} \in \mathcal{V}^{\star}$, but even if it's not, that doesn't matter: my point is that all elements of $\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathcal{V}^{\star}, \mathcal{T}{\mathrm{u}}$ are of the same type, namely "vectors".

The direct sum is defined for ANY two vector spaces over the same field. Do you have a space vector of matrices $V$ and another vector space of functions $W$? Then the elements of $V \oplus W$ are pairs $(A,f)$ and you sum coordinate-wise.

However, the elements of $\mathcal{V}^{\star}/\mathcal{T_{u}} = { {\boldsymbol{v} + \boldsymbol{t}  } \vert{} \boldsymbol{t} \in \mathcal{T}{\mathrm{u}}, \boldsymbol{v} \in \mathcal{V}^{\star} }$ are not ordered $n$-tuples: the elements of $\mathcal{V}^{\star}/\mathcal{T{u}}$ are sets themselves (affine subsets parallel to $\mathcal{T}{\mathrm{u}}$ to be exact), and these sets then contain vectors such as $\boldsymbol{z}{0}$.

@You acknowledge in your question already that a vector is something that belongs to a vector space. $\mathcal{V}^{\star} / \mathcal{T}_u$ is a vector space, so $z_0$, too, is a vector. Whether the elements are themselves sets is completely irrelevant. In fact, if you know anything about mathematical foundations then you probably know that pretty much everything is a set, in particular elements of, say, $\mathbb{R}^n$. Again, I see no issue with point 2, so please clarify.

@jjagmath I see no direct sums here.

@BenSteffan The title of the question is "Direct sum of quotient space and subspace"

@BartWolleswinkel As for point 1, the likely interpretation to me seems that $X / V + R_0$ is to be read as $X / (V + R_0)$, because reading it as $(X / V) + R_0$ doesn't make sense, as you correctly point out. Same goes for reading $V + R_0 / V$ as $(V + R_0) / V$.

@jjagmath But this is only for an external direct sum, and I'm not even sure these two vector spaces are over the same field (they could be, though). Here, we have $\mathcal{V}, \mathcal{R}_{0} \subseteq \mathcal{X}$, so these are subspace of that vector space.

@jjagmath Read the question. Do you think that "direct sum" is the correct interpretation of $+$ here? Is that the usual meaning of the symbol in linear algebra, when talking about subspaces? This is pretty clearly about an internal sum.

@BartWolleswinkel We don't call $V + W$ a "direct sum" generally, I guess that's why jjagmath is confused. That name's reserved for $V \oplus W$.

@BenSteffan In regards to my second question: assuming that both $\boldsymbol{z}{0} \in \mathcal{V}^{\star} $ and $\mathcal{T}{u} \subseteq \mathcal{V}^{\star} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is true (which it is in this context), the following must be incorrect: $\boldsymbol{z}{0} \in \mathcal{V}^{\star} / \mathcal{T}{\mathrm{u}}$, because $\mathcal{V}^{\star} $ and $ \mathcal{V}^{\star} / \mathcal{T}_{\mathrm{u}}$ have, by definition, different elements, and therefore a direct comparison is impossible. Is this a correct statement?

@BartWolleswinkel ...and it would be, technically, but two things: There's no statement that $z_0 \in V^$ in your excerpt. It reads to me as a definition: "Let $z_0 \in V^ / T_u$ be an element (which is a sufficiently small initial condition [...])." As the question is right now, there's no issue, but I'm not going to read the paper to find out whether this reading is correct. If you think there's an issue, you should bring forward evidence that there actually is. The second thing is, on an offchance, that sometimes people identify vectors with their images in quotient spaces.

@BenSteffan Apologies, I did not know that; I was under the impression that this was called the internal direct sum, how should one call it?

@BartWolleswinkel I guess "internal direct sum" is fine, but don't drop the "internal" :) I would probably call it the internal sum.

@BenSteffan, I've updated the question with your suggestions.
